# How to Animate Transforms in code behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, storyboard, transform

I have a  Button. For some reason, I would like to apply transforms in code behind. And The transforms work fine. But when I try to add animations on the transforms, the animations don't take effect. My code is as below.

```
<Grid x:Name="grid">
    <Button Height="40" Width="120" Content="Button"
            x:Name="button" Click="button_Click"> 
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

and in codebehind when button Clicked is :

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var animation = new DoubleAnimation(0, 20, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)));
    var story = new Storyboard();
    story.Children.Add(animation);
    Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, button);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath(TranslateTransform.YProperty));
    story.Begin();
}
```

Comment: Is the issue because you are using `StoryBoard.SetTarget(animation, Button)` and `StoryBoard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new ())` instead of using `story.SetTarget()` etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to animate a TranslateTransform, there has to be one assigned to the Button's `RenderTransform` or `LayoutTransform` property, either in XAML

```
<Button x:Name="button" Click="button_Click" ...>
    <Button.RenderTransform>
        <TranslateTransform/>
    </Button.RenderTransform>
</Button>
```

or in code behind

```
button.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform();
```

---

Then you do not need a Storyboard, because you can directly animate the transform like

```
var animation = new DoubleAnimation(0, 20, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

button.RenderTransform.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, animation);
```

---

With a Storyboard, you would have to set the correct property path:

```
var animation = new DoubleAnimation(0, 20, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, button);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.X"));

var story = new Storyboard();
story.Children.Add(animation);
story.Begin();
```